# How to fade to display: inline-block

Tags: jquery, fade

In my page I have a bunch (about 30) dom nodes that should be added invisible, and fade in when they are fully loaded.
The elements need a display: inline-block style.

I would like to use the jquery .fadeIn() function. This requires that the element initially has a display: none; rule to initially hide it.
After the fadeIn() the elements off course have the default display: inherit;

How can I use the fade functionality with a display value other than inherit?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use jQuery's [animate](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate#paramsdurationeasingcallback) function to change the opacity yourself, leaving the display unaffected.

Comment: I like this solution better, keeps the CSS out of my JS.

Comment: @joshuadelange not really, opacity is also CSS

Comment: +1 for focusing the engineering process of showing/hiding elments on where it should be.

Answer (score 248):

`$("div").fadeIn().css("display","inline-block");`

Comment: This is definitely the better answer.

Comment: Great answer! Even better, you can leave it empty to default to whatever you have in your CSS: `$("div").fadeIn().css("display","");`

Comment: This really ought to be the accepted answer; the existing accepted answer is more of a comment.

Comment: `$("div").fadeIn("400", function(){ $(this).css("display","inline-block"); });`
to be sure that display:inline-block is done when the fadein is finished

Comment: it doesn't work for me... applied on a div with an initial display style set to none using a class. Inspecting the element I see that for some milliseconds, right after calling the fadeIn, it has inline-block in its style, then style is set to block. with Simon suggestion the effect is not nice, as during the fadeIn the element is displayed as block

Comment: In IE edge this causes a flicker effect which makes this route unusable for that browser

Comment: Best solution in 2019

Comment: woosh ... you are now happy

Answer (score 11):

Just to flesh out Phil's good idea, here is a fadeIn() that loads fades in each element with the class .faded in turn, converted to animate() :

Old:

```
$(".faded").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 300).fadeIn();
});
```

New:

```
$(".faded").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 300).css('opacity',0).animate({'opacity': 1}, 500);
});
```

Hope that help another jQuery newb like myself :)
If there's a better way to do that, please tell us!

Answer (score 9):

Makura's answer did not work for me so my solution was

```
<div id="div" style="display: none">Some content</div>

$('#div').css('display', 'inline-block').hide().fadeIn();
```

`hide` immediately applies `display: none` but before that it saves the current display value in the jQuery data cache which will be restored by the subsequent animation calls.

So the `div` starts statically defined as `display: none`. Then it is set to `inline-block` and immediately hidden just to be faded in back to `inline-block`

Answer (score 2):

According to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/show/) for `.show()`,

> If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

So my solution to this problem was to apply a css rule to a class display: inline-block on the element, then I added another class called "hide" which applies display: none; When I `.show()` on the element, it showed inline.

Comment: I would assume that this should also work when you set `#el{display:inline-block;display:none;}` and then run `$('#el').fadeIn();` you get inline-block. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This works even with `display:none` preset by css. Use

```
$('#element').fadeIn().addClass('displaytype');
```

(and also `$('#element').fadeOut().removeClass('displaytype');`)

with setup in CSS:

```
#element.displaytype{display:inline-block;}
```

I consider this a workaround as I believe `fadeIn()` should work so that it would just remove the last rule - `display:none` when set to `#element{display:inline-block;display:none;}` but it is malfunctioningly removing both.