# Firing event for two times in a Table

Tags: jquery

I am trying to fire parent  click event whenever an input change happens.
Below is my code, it is firing Click event for two times.

```
                  $('TABLE TBODY TR TD INPUT').change(function()
                  {
                   $(this).parents('TD').click();
                  });
                  $('TABLE TBODY TR TD').click(function()
                  {
                   alert("Clicked me...");
                  });
```

Here is my HTML Code

```
      <table>
      <tr><td>foo<input type="radio"></td><td>foo<input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
      <tr><td>foo<input type="radio"></td><td>foo<input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
      <tr><td>foo<input type="radio"></td><td>foo<input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
      </table>
```

Where is the mistake...

Comment: why not just use .change()? instead of using both the .click() and .change()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('TABLE TBODY TR TD INPUT').change(function() {
    clicky(this.parents('TD'));
});
$('TABLE TBODY TR TD').click(function clicky(parentElement) {
    alert("Clicked me...");
});
```

so the `input` is also in `td` so both are being clicked.
    this only returns one alert, but I have a feeling you dont want to alert, but rather change the parent element.

**but I bet you probably want the following**

```
$('TABLE TBODY TR TD INPUT').change(function() {
    clicky($(this).parents('TD'));
});

 function clicky(parentElement) {
    $(parentElement).toggleClass('clicked');

};
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/nFtzJ/

here every time the input changes, the parent `<td>` has the class .clicked toggled, of course this can be changed, but its almost a faux pas to use `alert();` in production.

Comment: for the record, this question was accepted before the 

**but I bet you probably want the following** addition.

Answer (score 1):

try something like.
[this](http://jsfiddle.net/eDStK/)

```
$('TABLE TBODY TR TD INPUT').change(function() {
   alert("Clicked me...");
});
```

Comment: um.. ? why does your jsfiddle link to a jsfiddle I made for a different question last night? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514985/jquery-slideup-problem/6515002#6515002