# How to add display:inline-block in a jQuery show() function?

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have some code like this:

```
function switch_tabs(obj) {
    $('.tab-content').hide();
    $('.tabs a').removeClass("selected");

    var id = obj.attr("rel");
    $('#' + id).show();
    obj.addClass("selected");
}
```

The show function adds `display:block`. But I would like to add `display:inline-block` instead of block.

Comment: You'll need to provide some more details. It works for me in a quick test: http://jsfiddle.net/DD3Sf/ .

Comment: @gijs Sorry its working now. I think its some cache problem. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Instead of `show`, try to use CSS to hide and show the content.

```
function switch_tabs(obj) {
    $('.tab-content').css('display', 'none'); // you could still use `.hide()` here
    $('.tabs a').removeClass("selected");
    var id = obj.attr("rel");

    $('#' + id).css('display', 'inline-block');
    obj.addClass("selected");
}
```

Comment: This might seem obvious, but if you still want to utilize the timing aspect of `show` (`$("#id").show(500)`), just append the `css` function to it: `$("#id").show(500).css("display", "inline-block");`

Comment: I would take it a step further and take care of all the hiding/showing using CSS classes, not jQuery.

``$('.tab-content').addClass('hidden'); (...) $('#' + id).removeClass('hidden');``

In the CSS: ``.hidden { display: none !important }``

Comment: Even though this is the accepted answer but it doesn't reflect what's stated in jquery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/show/):
_This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "block" ), except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline._

So to have a default `display` you need to add a class in your css with `display:inline-block;` then call `hide()` and `show()` using the element's id. This is cleaner and more predictable code and easier to style.

Comment: @AbdullahAdeeb the problem is you would need to `hide()` by js on page load. Setting `#element{display:inline-block;display:none;}` doesn't do. I think the cleanest solution is `$('#element').fadeIn().addClass('displaytype');` - better than answer above, because you can set different `.displaytype`s in css and have one showing function in js. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091322/how-to-fade-to-display-inline-block/48401910#48401910

Answer (score 39):

Setting the CSS property after you have used `.show()` should work. Maybe you are targeting the wrong element on your HTML page.

```
 $('#foo').css('display', 'inline-block');
```

But if you are not using any effects of `.show(), .hide()` why don't you set those CSS properties manually like:

```
$('#foo').css('display','none'); 
$('#foo').css('display','inline-block');
```

Comment: Note that jquery show/hide/toggle restores previous display values. So if you hide it with jquery, calling show will work.

Comment: "Setting the CSS property after you have used .show() should work."  Whats the point of using show() if you are just going to manually update the css anyway?

Answer (score 11):

Use css() just after show() or fadeIn() like this:

```
$('div.className').fadeIn().css('display', 'inline-block');
```

Answer (score 5):

Razz's solution would work for the `.hide()` and `.show()` methods but would not work for the `.toggle()` method.

Depending upon the scenario, having a css class `.inline_block { display: inline-block; }` and calling `$(element).toggleClass('inline_block')` solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

I did that

```
function showPanels()  {
    $('.panels').show("slow");
    $('.panels').css('display','inline-block');
}
```

works like a charm.

Comment: Is that an answer or an acknowledgement..?

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
$('#foo').show(0).css('display','inline-block');
```

Comment: The `show()` in this is pointless. This is the same as `$('#foo').css('display','inline-block');`

Comment: @Liam Not pointless. You can change the 0 to ease in, or modify this to gain access to other unique `show` options.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) insted of show/hide

Something like this:

```
function switch_tabs(obj)
{
    $('.tab-content').animate({opacity:0},3000);
    $('.tabs a').removeClass("selected");
    var id = obj.attr("rel");

    $('#'+id).animate({opacity:1},3000);
    obj.addClass("selected");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want both the animation and to set the display property at the end. In that case you better use `show()` callback as shown below

```js
$("#my_obj").show(400,function() {
    $("#my_obj").css("display","inline-block")
}) ;
```

This way you will achieve both the results.

Comment: This is not correct, you'd end up with the `inline-block` mode only after the whole animation ran. That means it would "pop" between `block` and `inline-block` after the 400ms.

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
.demo-ele{display:inline-block}
</style>

<div class="demo-ele" style="display:none">...</div>

<script>
$(".demo-ele").show(1000);//hide first, show with inline-block
<script>
```

Answer (score 1):

actually jQuery simply clears the value of the 'display' property, and doesn't set it to 'block' (see internal implementation of jQuery.showHide()) -

```
   function showHide(elements, show) {
    var display, elem, hidden,
```

...

```
         if (show) {
            // Reset the inline display of this element to learn if it is
            // being hidden by cascaded rules or not
            if (!values[index] && display === "none") {
                elem.style.display = "";
            }
```

...

```
        if (!show || elem.style.display === "none" || elem.style.display === "") {
            elem.style.display = show ? values[index] || "" : "none";
        }
    }
```

Please note that you can override $.fn.show()/$.fn.hide(); storing original display in element itself when hiding (e.g. as an attribute or in the $.data()); and then applying it back again when showing.

Also, using css ***important!*** will probably not work here - since setting a style inline is usually stronger than any other rule

Answer (score 0):

The best .let it's parent `display :inline-block` or add a parent `div` what CSS only have `display :inline-block`.

Answer (score -5):

Best way is to add !important suffix to the selector .

Example:

```
 #selector{
     display: inline-block !important;                   
}
```

Comment: doesn't this prevent .hide() ?

Comment: !important is only necessary in edge cases when there is no other option. Not the right way to approach this problem in my opinion when it can be fixed with better jQuery code.

Comment: The *important* thing to remember about `!important` is that it's *important* to not use it.