# jquery show/hide when using inline-block

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML and CSS that looks like this:

```
<div id="TheContainer">
<div class="MyDivs"></div>
<div class="MyDivs" id="ThisDiv"></div>
</div>

#TheContainer{text-align:center;}
.MyDivs{margin:0px auto;display:inline-block;}
#ThisDiv{display:none;}
```

I'm using `inline-block` and margin:0px auto so that the `MyDivs` are centered within `TheContainer`. The problem is that when I do this:

```
$('#TheContainer').children().hide();
$('#ThisDiv').show();
```

then `ThisDiv` isn't centered anymore because the display changed from none to block instead of inline-block like I have it in the CSS definition.

I know I could write `.css('display','none')` and `.css('display','inline-block')` but I was wondering if there was a way to make this work by keeping `.show()`

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make an extension to jQuery...

```
$.fn.showInlineBlock = function () {
    return this.css('display', 'inline-block');
};
```

Useage would be:

```
$('#whatever').showInlineBlock();
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/et2mZ/)

Comment: Also I believe you could do the same thing just `$.fn.show` to overwrite the default jQuery one, but that might be dangerous in changes certain things to inline-block that shouldn't be!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260009/jquery-show-function-display-inline-block-how