# jQuery .show() adds style="display:inline-block" to elements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, show-hide

I'm working on a site I inherited at work that shows donation progress using progress bars / labels. The majority of the lists will have 9 years in the (e.g. 1990-1999) but the last one has 13 (2000-2012). Because of this, I have a javascript function `showHiddenBars()` which shows / hides the respective elements.

On first load, everything displays correctly (2000-2012 is displayed by default) but after hiding them and then showing them, it messes up the layout. From what I can tell via Google Chrome's inspector is that when the `.show()` function is used it is adding `style="display: inline-block"` to my span element which houses the label. I am using the `clip` easing effect of jQuery UI with the show and hide functions.

How do I prevent .show from adding style="display: inline-block;"

Full Javascript: http://pastebin.com/ZmbQqwWF

Full HTML: http://pastebin.com/mf6W1ahF

Example Site: http://kirsches.us/3000Strong/decadeProgress.html

The javascript:

```
function showHiddenBars() {
    "use strict";
    //show the bars we aren't using.
    $('#decade10').show("clip");
    $('#decade11').show("clip");
    $('#decade12').show("clip");
    $('#decade13').show("clip");
    $('#decade10label').show("clip");
    $('#decade11label').show("clip");
    $('#decade12label').show("clip");
    $('#decade13label').show("clip");
    $('#decade10AmountGiven').show("clip");
    $('#decade11AmountGiven').show("clip");
    $('#decade12AmountGiven').show("clip");
   $('#decade13AmountGiven').show("clip");
}
function hideHiddenBars() {
   "use strict";
    //hide the bars we aren't using.
    $('#decade10').hide("clip");
    $('#decade11').hide("clip");
    $('#decade12').hide("clip");
    $('#decade13').hide("clip");
    $('#decade10label').hide("clip");
    $('#decade11label').hide("clip");
    $('#decade12label').hide("clip");
    $('#decade13label').hide("clip");
    $('#decade10AmountGiven').hide("clip");
    $('#decade11AmountGiven').hide("clip");
    $('#decade12AmountGiven').hide("clip");
    $('#decade13AmountGiven').hide("clip");
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="decadeProgressContainer">
    <span class="titleFontNoBorder" id="decade1label">2000</span>
    <div id="decade1" class="progressBarSpacingTop"></div>
    <span id="decade1AmountGiven">$130,000</span><br />

    <span class="titleFontNoBorder" id="decade2label">2001</span>
    <div id="decade2" class="progressBarSpacing"></div>
    <span id="decade2AmountGiven">$130,000</span><br />

    <span class="titleFontNoBorder" id="decade3label">2002</span>
    <div id="decade3" class="progressBarSpacing"></div>
    <span id="decade3AmountGiven">$130,000</span><br />

    <span class="titleFontNoBorder" id="decade4label">2003</span>
    <div id="decade4" class="progressBarSpacing"></div>
    <span id="decade4AmountGiven">$130,000</span><br />

    <span class="titleFontNoBorder" id="decade5label">2004</span>
    <div id="decade5" class="progressBarSpacing"></div>
    <span id="decade5AmountGiven">$130,000</span><br />

    <span class="titleFontNoBorder" id="decade6label">2005</span>
    <div id="decade6" class="progressBarSpacing"></div>
    <span id="decade6AmountGiven">$130,000</span><br />

    <span class="titleFontNoBorder" id="decade7label">2006</span>
    <div id="decade7" class="progressBarSpacing"></div>
    <span id="decade7AmountGiven">$130,000</span><br />

    <span class="titleFontNoBorder" id="decade8label">2007</span>
    <div id="decade8" class="progressBarSpacing"></div>
    <span id="decade8AmountGiven">$130,000</span><br />

    <span class="titleFontNoBorder" id="decade9label">2008</span>
    <div id="decade9" class="progressBarSpacing"></div>
    <span id="decade9AmountGiven">$130,000</span><br />

    <span class="titleFontNoBorder" id="decade10label">2009</span>
    <div id="decade10" class="progressBarSpacing"></div>
    <span id="decade10AmountGiven">$130,000</span><br />

    <span class="titleFontNoBorder" id="decade11label">2010</span>
    <div id="decade11" class="progressBarSpacing"></div>
    <span id="decade11AmountGiven">$130,000</span><br />

    <span class="titleFontNoBorder" id="decade12label">2011</span>
    <div id="decade12" class="progressBarSpacing"></div>
    <span id="decade12AmountGiven">$130,000</span><br />

    <span class="titleFontNoBorder" id="decade13label">2012</span>
    <div id="decade13" class="progressBarSpacing"></div>
    <span id="decade13AmountGiven">$130,000</span>
</div>
<!--end div #decadeProgressContainer-->
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do I prevent .show from adding style="display: inline-block;"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Explicitly set the style for the visibility the way you want it:  don't rely on hide() and show():

```
element.css('display', 'none'); equivalent of hide()
element.css('display', 'inline-block'); equivalent of show()
element.css('display', 'block'); What you want
```

Comment: show() doesn't set display:inline-block.  It will set it to whatever the starting value is in the css.  So if the starting value is block, it will set to block.  If display:none is used in the css, then it will default to display:inline.

Comment: It seems that `show()` will result in CSS `display:block;`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9260009/1066234

Answer (score 3):

I think if the defaut style for the element is inline then it will add inline-block, at least for select dropdowns it also adds inline-block. If you need to add block then use the .css

```
$('#el').css('display','block');
```

You can still use .hide() to hide, that does not need to change