# div changes its margins when select option is changed

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$('#seltags').change(function() {
  var obj = $('#' + $(this).val());
  $('.txtags').hide();
  obj.show();
});
```

```css
.seltags {
  display: block;
  padding: 1px 7px;
  width: 100%;
}

.txtags {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 9px;
  resize: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-top: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.tagsimg {
  display: none;
}

.divbottom {
  height: 14px;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='seltags' id='seltags'>
  <option value='tagsart'>TAGS ARTICLES</option>
  <option value='tagsimg'>TAGS IMAGES</option>
</select>

<textarea class='txtags' id='tagsart' rows="5"></textarea>
<textarea class='txtags tagsimg' id='tagsimg' rows="5"></textarea>

<div class='divbottom'></div>
```

`divbottom` gets a top margin (about five pixels) when `seltags` is changed to second option, and lose that margin when it is returned to the first option.

Can anyone help me what's wrong here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The margin appears because when the select box is changed and the second option is chosen, the text area that was hidden now gets `display: inline-block;` to show it, and the offset from being hidden causes the margin jump.

Try adding `vertical-align: middle;` to the styles of the `.txtags` class element.

```js
$('#seltags').change(function() {
  var obj = $('#' + $(this).val());
  $('.txtags').hide();
  obj.show();
});
```

```css
.seltags {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 7px;
  width: 100%;
}

.txtags {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 9px;
  resize: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-top: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.tagsimg {
  display: none;
}

.divbottom {
  height: 14px;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='seltags' id='seltags'>
  <option value='tagsart'>TAGS ARTICLES</option>
  <option value='tagsimg'>TAGS IMAGES</option>
</select>

<textarea class='txtags' id='tagsart' rows="5"></textarea>
<textarea class='txtags tagsimg' id='tagsimg' rows="5"></textarea>

<div class='divbottom'></div>
```

Comment: how do you know that hidden textarea becomes `inline-block`? It is declared as `block` in css.

Comment: Because jQuery object.show() sets the css style on the tag to "display: inline-block". You can watch this occur if you inspect the element in the DOM while selecting options.

Comment: Pls, how can I exactly inspect this. In source code, in consola... where?

Comment: If you're using Chrome, right click on the visible textarea, then select "Inspect Element" from the context menu. You should then see the dom elements. Try selecting the second option, and you should see the "display" style toggle on your textareas.

Answer (score 0):

The margin appears because when the second option is chosen, the `#tagsimg` element gets `display: inline-block` inline style.
In order to remove this margin, you need to add `vertical-align: middle` to the styles of the `#tagsimg` element or find out why the `display: inline-block` is added and change that.
You can read why jQuery does it, and how to avoid it in this StackOverflow question: [jQuery .show() adds style="display:inline-block" to elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689966/jquery-show-adds-style-displayinline-block-to-elements)

Answer (score 0):

it's not a margin, it's the `textarea` ( `.txtags` ) that you show and hide that pushes it down a bit necause when shown it gets `display:inline-block` ,

add `.obj.show().css({'display': 'block'});` so both textareas behave the same

```js
$('#seltags').change(function(){
 var obj = $('#' + $(this).val());
 $('.txtags').hide();
 obj.show().css({'display': 'block'});
});
```

```css
.seltags{
 display:block;
 padding:1px 7px;
 width:100%;
}

.txtags{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 padding:5px 9px;
 outline:none;
 border:1px solid #999;
 border-radius:9px;
 resize:none;
 overflow-y:scroll;
 margin-top:13px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

.tagsimg{
 display:none;
}

.divbottom{
height:14px;
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='seltags' id='seltags'>
<option value='tagsart'>TAGS ARTICLES</option>
<option value='tagsimg'>TAGS IMAGES</option>
</select>

<textarea class='txtags' id='tagsart' rows="5"></textarea>
<textarea class='txtags tagsimg' id='tagsimg' rows="5"></textarea>

<div class='divbottom'></div>
```

Comment: That is fun how your answer will fix it and keeps the space and mine doesn't keeps the space...

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown i actually edited the answer right before your comment .. same approach as yours

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but the `div.divbottom` is not getting any margin or padding at all. The problem is that when you show the `.tagsimg` it is getting `display: inline-block` instead of just `block` which is the initial state of `.txtags`. Making `.tagsimg` be hidden by jQuery instead of starting with `display:none` makes jQuery change it to `display:inline-block` when shown which fix it.

```js
$('#seltags').change(function(){
 var obj = $('#' + $(this).val());
 $('.txtags').hide();
 obj.show();
});

$('.tagsimg').hide();
```

```css
.seltags{
 display:block;
 padding:1px 7px;
 width:100%;
}

.txtags{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 padding:5px 9px;
 outline:none;
 border:1px solid #999;
 border-radius:9px;
 resize:none;
 overflow-y:scroll;
 margin-top:13px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

.tagsimg{
 display:block;
}

.divbottom{
height:14px;
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='seltags' id='seltags'>
<option value='tagsart'>TAGS ARTICLES</option>
<option value='tagsimg'>TAGS IMAGES</option>
</select>

<textarea class='txtags' id='tagsart' rows="5"></textarea>
<textarea class='txtags tagsimg' id='tagsimg' rows="5"></textarea>

<div class='divbottom'></div>
```

Comment: how do you know that hidden textarea becomes `inline-block`? It is declared as `block` in css.

Comment: @puerto I'm almost sure that when you execute `show()`, jQuery gets the value that was once declared in css and uses it. If it was already `display:none`, jQuery applies `inline-block` as default.

Answer (score 0):

both textareas should be either `inline-block` or `block` its the mixture of two which is causing the behavior

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st textarea is displayed as a `block`.
But the trick here is that when you make your 2nd textarea appear, it appears as an `inline-block`.

I suggest you to use `inline-block` or delete the property.
Here is a working snippet with some other comments:

```js
// Optimized function
$('#seltags').change(function() {
  $('.txtags').hide();
  $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

```css
.seltags {
  display: block;
  padding: 1px 7px;
  width: 100%;
}

.txtags {
  /* display: inline-block; /* Here is what I changed! */
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 9px;
  resize: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-top: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.hidden { /* Changed name */
  display: none;
}

.divbottom {
  height: 14px;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='seltags' id='seltags'>
  <option value='tagsart'>TAGS ARTICLES</option>
  <option value='tagsimg'>TAGS IMAGES</option>
</select>
<textarea class='txtags' id='tagsart' rows="5"></textarea>
<textarea class='txtags hidden' id='tagsimg' rows="5"></textarea>
<div class='divbottom'></div>
```

On a side note, I don't understand why your 2nd `textarea` appear as `inline-block`.

Here is an extract of `show()` documentation:
“The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "block" ), except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.”
(link: http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: is there any jquery or css address to complain about this?