# jQuery fadeIn() results in display: block for inline element

Tags: jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/dk5Ua/

```
<div></div>

var $span = $('<span>foo</span>');

$span.hide();
$("div").append($span);
$span.fadeIn();
```

You'll notice the resulting span has inline style `display: block;` instead of inline.

This is the resulting html:

```
<span style="display: block;">foo</span>
```

How do I get the fadeIn() to result in display: inline?

Comment: Wait, what is the question again?

Comment: It looks pretty inline to me.

Comment: in the fiddle, it is block. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By cloning the original object I can call fadeIn and it gives me an inline style.

```
var $htm = $('<span/>')
, $divs = $('div');

$divs.replaceWith(function(){
   return $htm.clone().fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Answer (score 14):

I just found a simple solution to a similar problem. In your case, the fix would be this:

```
$span.css('display', 'inline').hide().fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm with Adrian; that really wasn't a question.  But you are correct: jQuery does a very naive translation of display properties when you use anything that show/hides elements (eg. show, hide, togle, fadeOut, etc.).

I've honestly never understood why they do this (it'd be much simpler to simply set display to:

```
isShown ? '' : 'none';
```

instead of their logic, which is essentially:

```
isShown ? 'block' : 'none';
```

) but they have reasons for just about everything they do, so I imagine they have a some logic behind setting the wrong display types on things.

*** EDIT ***

As I suspected, the jQuery people did have their reasons (see the comments from jfriend00); also I see that there's an actual question in the question now:

> How do I get the fadeIn() to result in display: inline?

The answer is that you need to look at how fadeIn works; essentially it's just:

```
this.animate({opacity: "show"}, speed, easing, callback );
```

In other words, it's roughly equivalent to:

```
this.animate({opacity: '100%'}, speed, easing, function() {
    this.css('display', 'block')
});
```

(WARNING: I'm not actually a big user of jQuery's animation features, so while the above code should work, I make no promises).

Given that, if you want to set the display to something else (like say `'inline'`), you can do:

```
this.animate({opacity: '100%'}, speed, easing, function() {
    this.css('display', 'inline') // or you could use this.css('display', '')
});
```

Comment: They probably can't use `isShown ? '' : 'none';` because they have to override any CSS that might be in effect and setting display to `''` would allow the CSS to be in effect rather than forcing the object to be shown.

Comment: I imagine that's because inline elements, being a part of the flow, cause greater disruption when changing their display property, as they force a reflow of everything around them? I suppose you could animate a change in rgba() on the element, but that wouldn't be supported all that well across all browsers, either.

Comment: @jfriend00 It doesn't "allow the CSS to be in effect" though; it replaces whatever existing value is there with `''`, which (in every browser I know) sets the property back to its default value (which will be the correct `display` type, eg. inline for spans, block for divs, etc.).

Comment: @morei57 That might be the reason, although personally I'd rather have  a few more reflows and the correct display types /shrug

Comment: @machineghost - you didn't understand my comment.  Setting `style.display=''` sets it to default which allows CSS rules in a style file specified by a selector (not set specifically on the style attribute of the object) to be in effect.  Setting `style.display = 'inline'` or `style.display = 'block'` overrides the CSS rules giving a known result.  There is difference and jQuery probably wants to override the CSS rules to get to a known result.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok, now I understand what you're getting at: if someone adds `div#whatever {display:none}` in a stylesheet, and jQuery uses `style.display = ''` as its show() operation, it won't work on that div. Still, it seems like jQuery could simply use `style.display = ''` as its show logic, and then check `if (!this.is(':visible')) style = 'block'`, so that it only clobbers the display style if someone used .show() on an element hidden by CSS ... but I guess there are performance implications to that.

Comment: `There is difference and jQuery probably wants to override the CSS rules to get to a known result.` - true, but it's not really any better, as it's still the wrong result. :)

Answer (score 2):

I found this extremely useful, and somewhat simpler (based on [MakuraYami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1235305/makurayami)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10322651/1009413) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091322/how-to-fade-to-display-inline-block)):

```
$span.fadeIn().css('display', 'inline');
```