# JQuery, CSS, Wrong Layout using show

Tags: jquery, css

I got the following code: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/CWP8E/), As you can see when you write somthing in the input the textarea shows up, The problem is just before the effect is finished a small gap is created between the submit input and the textarea, The interesting thing is that:

When i replace this line:

```
qCont.show("blind", {to: { display: "block"}}, 1500);
```

With this line:

```
qCont.css("display", "block");
```

The problem is solved, But i do want this effect is there a way to fix it and use the "show" effect, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. There's a bottom margin of 5px being applied to the textarea.

It's a hack, but I solved this by adding the following css:

```
#qContent
{
  margin-bottom: -5px !important;
}
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CWP8E/3/

As an alternative, you can add an anonymous function that executes AFTER the show effect animation. This also fixes the appearance (and I favor it a bit more):

```
qTitle.one("keydown" ,function(){
        qCont.show("blind", {to: { display: "block"}}, 1500, function() {
            $(this).css("display","block");
        });
    });
```

Here's the fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/CWP8E/4/

I'm still looking into WHY the 5px margin is being inserted (something in jQquery?), but the hacks above fix the visuals. I do understand it's a hack but sometimes that gets us going on our way.

When stepping through thee code, I noticed that the jQuery animation ends with the qTitle having a `display: inline-block` value, not `display: block` as anticipated. A quick search on Google reveals this second solution (with the anonymous completion function) to be recommended.

Here's a StackOverflow article that describes it:

[jQuery fadeIn() results in display: block for inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281300/jquery-fadein-results-in-display-block-for-inline-element)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
qCont.show("blind", {direction:"vertical"}, 1500);
```

Comment: Orangepill, Thank you for your answer i did try but it did not work.