# how fade in a flex box?

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox

How do I get a flex box to not be part of the page until I fade it in? I used to do this with 'display: 0;' and then use jQuery .fadeIn(). But now if I set display to 0, when I fade it in, of course I lose the flex-iness of the box. If I use jQuery to set display to flex, then it will just appear, not fade in.

### HTML

```
<div class="" id="popupContainer">
    <div class="flex-item-popup" id="popup">
        <div class="close"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-times-circle"></i></div>
        <h2></h2>
        <div class='text'></div>
        <div class="videos"></div>
        <div class="flex-container images"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#popupContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 15;
}
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //???
});
```

Comment: Very similar question, though related to `inline-block` it's the same underlying issue.  I couldn't find one specific to `flex` so I won't close as duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091322/how-to-fade-to-display-inline-block

Comment: You can set "display: flex" in the CSS and inline style="display: none" in HTML

Answer (score 148, accepted):

It seems a bit odd, but what you can do is in the css, set it to `display: none`.  Then the trick is to set the `display` to `flex` in your jquery and then hide it again, then `fadeIn`:

**CSS**:

```
#popupContainer {
    /* ... */

    display:none;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    /* ... */
}
```

**JS**:

```
$("#popupContainer")
    .css("display", "flex")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn();
```

This works because `fadeIn()` will set the item back to its previous non-hidden `display` value.  So setting `flex` and re-hiding it will set this "default" for it to be set back to.

http://jsfiddle.net/z2kxyjcq/1/

```js
$("#popupContainer")
    .css("display", "flex")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(2000);
```

```css
#popupContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:none;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 15;
    background-color: red;
}
#popupContainer *{
    border: 1px solid blue;
background-color: white;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" id="popupContainer">
<div class="flex-item-popup" id="popup">
    <div class="close"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-times-circle">1</i></div>
    <h2>2</h2>
    <div class='text'>a</div>
    <div class="videos">b</div>
    <div class="flex-container images">c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works very good, also good to know, you can also do it in reverse when doing something like a hover behavior, on Hover: .css("display", "flex").hide().fadeIn(); and leaving: fadeOut().hide().css("display", "none");

Answer (score 9):

Easiest and most clean way (if you can edit DOM) is to wrap the element, and fade the wrapper while having div with flex inside

```
<div class="popup" id="popupContainer">
  <div class="popup__flexbox">
    <div class="popup__flex-item" id="popup">
    <div class="popup__close">
       <i class="fa fa-2x fa-times-circle"></i>
    </div>
    <h2></h2>
    <div class='popup__text'></div>
    <div class="popup__videos"></div>
    <div class="popup__images"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.popup {
  display: none;
}

.popup__flexbox {
  display: flex;
}
```

js:

```
$("#popupContainer").fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set the opacity as 0 and animate:

```
$('#popupContainer').animate({
    opacity: 1
}, 'fast');
```

Comment: This, while a good alternative would cause a big white space in your page since the box would still be in the document flow but just invisible ^.^

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for. I could have an element already styled with `opacity: 0;` and then just animate it. No need to flip-flop on the display setting - that was causing glitching / flashing for me.

Comment: Some older versions of jQuery seem to set the display style in the `fadeTo` function, so I had to give up that shortcut and do it this way

Comment: If the content is appearing on top of another element you might have to add `visibility: hidden;` or `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: You probably don't want something like a conditional 'submit' button to just / be there / but be invisible.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var flex = $('#flex');

console.log(flex.css('display'));

flex.hide();

flex.velocity('fadeIn', {duration: 100, display: 'flex'});

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(flex.css('display'));
 }, 100);
```

```css
#flex{
  display: 'flex'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.min.js"></script>

<div id="flex"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Best CSS only solution for fadeIn or jQuery show to display flex is that:

```css
.fadeIn.fadeFlex[style*='display: block']{
    display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row fadeIn fadeFlex">
...
</div>
```