# How to replace display block with display flex in jQuery

Tags: jquery

The following css style rule is set to display none:

```
.modal {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    outline: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

When jQuery opens the modal, it adds the following style to me: display block, but I don't want a display block, but a display flex.

How can I make a display flex activate instead of the display block?

Code in https://jsfiddle.net/x4fqpn96/

> Note: It does not work, because it is implemented with ajax where information is sent to php and it returns a response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how fade in a flex box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904698/how-fade-in-a-flex-box)

Comment: @Phil If I saw it, I tried to use the example as it exposes it there, but it did not work, did not perform any action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

- Adding `display:flex` to the element even while it is hidden (and see if jQuery detexts it)
- otherwise, swap `fadeIn()` with `fadeIn().css('display', 'flex')` to explicitly set the `display`.