# Divs keep on displaying as block and not inline block

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to get `<div class="project-list">` to be `inline-block` but it keeps reverting back to `block`.

```
.project-list {
width:20%;
display:inline-block; }


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#one').delay(1300).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#two').delay(1500).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#three').delay(1700).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#four').delay(1900).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#five').delay(2100).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#six').delay(2300).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#seven').delay(2500).fadeIn(1000);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w58L2dn0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you use fadeIn for show the div, you can use 2 solutions:

```
$('#one').delay(1300).css({
        opacity: 0,
        display: 'inline-block'     
    }).animate({opacity:1},600);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lTasty/w58L2dn0/5/
OR

```
$('#one').delay(1300).fadeIn(1000).css("display","inline-block");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lTasty/w58L2dn0/2/

Comment: Why is fadeIn causing the problem?

Comment: because fadein force the display to block

Comment: The first solution was the best. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a jquery problem. fadeIn (and show etc) set the display as inline css. Eg. the element gets style="display:block" when its shown. See [How to fade to display: inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091322/how-to-fade-to-display-inline-block) for details on how you can construct your own animation that results in inline-block as the display.

Answer (score 1):

by default, jQuery show `display:block` you can override it by adding CSS rule into jQuery `.css("display", "inline-block")`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#one').css("display", "inline-block").delay(1300).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#two').css("display", "inline-block").delay(1500).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#three').css("display", "inline-block").delay(1700).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#four').css("display", "inline-block").delay(1900).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#five').css("display", "inline-block").delay(2100).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#six').css("display", "inline-block").delay(2300).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#seven').css("display", "inline-block").delay(2500).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w58L2dn0/4/)

Comment: with your code box are visibile before delay and fadeIn because you remove Display:none

Comment: @LTasty what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

In your html you have `style="display: block"`. In HTML we have 3 ways to insert CSS on page:

- External style sheet
- Internal style sheet
- Inline style

Your `style="display: block"` it's inline style sheet, and this style override all external style sheets and internal. In its turn internal override just external style sheets. And external doesn't override nothing.

Also you have `id` and `class` in the same tag. For example let's take `div` with `id="three"` you can set `display: none` to it. So how `id` more stronger than `class` you id properties override `class` properties.

Read more about adding CSS to HTML [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2).

Comment: This answer isn't completely correct. Presumably OP doesn't know that his inline styles are being automatically created by jQuery, which I think is the heart of the issue here. And external stylesheets can indeed override internal stylesheets if they are placed lower down in the `<head>` of the document (though I don't generally see it happen in the wild). As a side note, I think you meant `id="three"` rather than `id="#three"`.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister yep, I really mean id="three", thanks. But he just asked why he haven't `display: inline-block` and I explained why he puts it in style, but it does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fairly complex setup so why not just do them in order leaving out the id?  I simplified he CSS as well:

```
var showem2 = function (me, mydelay) {
    return $(me).delay(mydelay).css('display', 'inline-block').hide().fadeIn(1000);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".project-list").each(function (i) {
        showem2($(this), 500 * (i + 1));
    });
});
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/w58L2dn0/7/