# Trying to have a div fade in on button press with transition time and delay, but can't animate switch between display:none and display:inline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` on a website that is currently set up such that it starts at `opacity:0;` and transitions to `opacity:1;` on `button` press. I chose that since I found you couldn't have a switch from `display:none;` to `display:inline;` have a transition on `button` press. However, now when the page is viewed in smaller windows, there's a scroll bar, since the content is still there, just not view-able. What choices do I have? Can I somehow get the `div` to have `display:none;` and still fade in?

I have no knowledge of jQuery, so if that's somehow a solution to this problem could you guys spell it out very simply for me? I'll put a JSFiddle below.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ThatGuy7/g12g65wk/3/)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure `visibility` is what I'm looking for. This still produces a scroll bar with a smaller browser window, and it doesn't seem to be animate-able either; it doesn't wait for `animation-delay` or `transition-delay` nor does it fade in with `transition`. Thanks for the response though, @John!

Comment: @John `visibility:hidden;` still takes up space in the DOM, which would still produce a scrollbar for him

Comment: yes sorry, it was the other way around. `display` will remove the item as it was no there

Comment: Would something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/g12g65wk/7/) work?

Comment: I cannot immediately see the problem in the jsFiddle -- which DIV has the undesireable scrollbar?

Comment: @gibberish I believe he is talking about the `#abouttextbackground` that fades in when you click the About button. The scroll bar is on the window. He really probably needs a `@media` query to reduce the size of `#abouttextbackground` and it's contents on smaller window sizes.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091322/how-to-fade-to-display-inline-block

Comment: @gibberish, I'm not sure how big the console on JSFiddle is for you, but the link in my OP has a scroll bar if the window is too small, even when the visibility or opacity is set to hidden/0.

Comment: @zgood, That's fantastic! That looks perfect, I'm going to try it on my original HTML right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution (if you don't mind a slightly different type of animation) would be to set your div to `transform:scale(0);` then animate both `opacity` and `scale` with a display class.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g12g65wk/7/).

CSS

```
#abouttextbackground {
    ...
  opacity:0;
  transform:scale(0);
}
    #abouttextbackground.show{
      opacity:1;
      transform:scale(1);
    }
```

JS

```
var about_text = document.getElementById("abouttextbackground");                
about_text.classList.toggle('show');
```

If you want to keep the animation the same then @gibberish's solution would work better.

Comment: Both your and @gibberish's solutions are valid and extremely helpful, but I'm choosing this one as the solution since I find this style of animation actually fits better. Thanks a bunch for the help!

Comment: np glad to help. If the horizontal scroll bar becomes an issue you can add this style: `#abouttext img{ max-width: 100%; }` and add `overflow: hidden;` to your `#abouttextbackground` as demo'ed [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g12g65wk/10/) and you may want to consider some `@media` queries to reduce your heading and font sizes on smaller screens.

Comment: are `@media` queries something to do with jQuery? It sounds like I'll have to start learning about jQuery soon.

Comment: @ThatGuy7 no is CSS. It allows you to define certain styles at certain screen sizes. So for smaller screens you can make your heading font slightly smaller so it fits in the div area better

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the visibility of the vertical scrollbar for that DIV. In your jsFiddle example, I did this for the `body` element:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/g12g65wk/8/)</kbd>

**CSS:**

```
body {overflow-y:hidden;}
```

**JS:**

```
var scrollvis = 'hidden';
function funcAbout() {
    scrollvis = (scrollvis=='hidden') ? 'auto' : 'hidden';
    $('body').css({'overflow-y':scrollvis});
```